# splitting csv files in pandas on python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to load a spec column in pandas but it keep printing me the name of the column and also it skips the first part

can anyone help me?

this is the code i am using:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)

df_iter = pd.read_csv('tweets.csv', chunksize=10000, iterator=True, usecols=["text"])

df_iter = df_iter[1:]

   for iter_num in enumerate(df_iter, -1):

      for line in df_iter:

         print(line)
```

Comment: Hello, please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, 
Since you are reading the csv in chunks, I would assume that the file is very large. You need to loop through those chunks to read all the data of the file. Then you can merge / concatenate all these chunks.

Second thing, enumerate() is not for dataframes. You need iterrows().

Something like this -

```
import pandas as pd 
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
df_iter = pd.read_csv('tweets.csv', chunksize=10000, iterator=True, usecols=["text"])
df_records = [] #list 
for chunk in df_iter:
    df_records.append(chunk)

df_new = pd.concat(df_records)
for iter_num, value in df_new.iterrows():
    print(value[0])
```